How to find the country/nation/province of a specific point when using google maps?
I'm currently using google maps and exploring random islands in the middle of the ocean. But Google map is not showing to which country/nation this Islands belong to. Is there any way to find this? For example I'm looking at this Island.
https://maps.app.goo.gl/UXTXeZiZxkxvB3eYA
How can we find the nation/state to which this island belongs to?
The Island does not have a name or anything that I can use to search!
Or this Island: https://maps.app.goo.gl/orZpLebN9XZcKu2k7
its called "Nightingale Island", This is probably British overseas territory, but atleast map is not showing it directly. How can we see that?

The first place to look is the side panel. It might be collapsed. If that happens to you, click the Expand side panel button.

Then, look at the side panel content. Your mileage might vary (due to personalization, the results that you get might be different from the results that other people could get). If the information isn't there, it's very likely that it's not available in Google Maps, and you should use another service.
The second thing you might want to try is right-click over a place of interest, then select What's here?

The bottom of the screen will show a dialog
For the first link

For the second link

Again, you should use another service if the information isn't there.
One alternative service that you might try is Google Earth.
Note: Stack Exchange has a site specialized in Geographic Information Systems: https://gis.stackexchange.com/. Look at its tour page to learn the site's scope and essential workings.
Google Maps Help
Related help article from the Google Maps Help Center

Understand country borders and names


If you can't find information in Google Maps, you will need to use other resources. Not every island is named and even those that are may not indicate under whose sovereignty they lie, and/or may have contested or otherwise nuanced politics that may not be fully expressed in Maps.
Below is an image with a green-circled checkmark marking your coordinates in the Indian Ocean.
It appears to be part of the Cargados Carajos Shoals (Saint Brandon) an archipelago of sand banks, shoals and islets belonging to the Republic of Mauritius (Wikipedia source).
I discovered this by using Google search to identify sovereign bodies close to your coordinates and ultimately found that Mauritius was identified as including "St. Brandon (Cargados Carajos shoals)).
When I geolocated some of the archipelago's named islands it showed that they surrounded your coordinates.

Resources:

wikipedia.com

St. Brandon (aka "Cargados Carajos Shoals")
International waters
Exclusive economic zone
Territorial waters


cia.gov

World and Regional Maps
Political World Map (8.4 MB pdf)



